Why boolean values are not set properly in DB
Here I'm trying to set Boolean values using JPA but in return the field name and the value both are different from what I have actually passed.
If you look at my request, I have passed isCouponAplied but in return I got just couponAplied.
package com.example.curd_example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "OrderDetails")
@Getter
@Setter
public class OrderDetails implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Order_detail_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ItemDetails itemDetails;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private double discountedAmount;
    private double discountPercent;
    private boolean isCouponAplied;
    private double discountedAmountForCoupon;
    private double totalSavings;
}


Request:
{
    "name": "Sankar",
    "itemDetails":{
        "quantity":1,
        "itemName": "DOSA"
    },
    "quantity": 2,
    "price": 39.98,
    "discountedAmount": 10,
    "discountPercent": 32.27,
    "isCouponAplied": true,
    "discountedAmountForCoupon": 10,
    "totalSavings": 20
}

Response:
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Sankar",
    "itemDetails": {
        "id": 2,
        "quantity": 1,
        "itemName": "DOSA"
    },
    "quantity": 2,
    "price": 39.98,
    "discountedAmount": 10.0,
    "discountPercent": 32.27,
    "discountedAmountForCoupon": 10.0,
    "totalSavings": 20.0,
    "couponAplied": false
}

DATA IN DB
It should store the value what I have passed actually.

I suspect that it's probably because by default JPA creates a "isXXX" getter method for boolean fields and presumes that the field name is "XXX". Try with the field renamed to just "couponApplied".

@legendofawesomeness lombok creates getter method, not JPA.

Thanks for catching that @ShubhamPatil

Using Lombok Getter/Setter for boolean values will generate isXXXX for getter methods, reference, so your boolean field should be renamed couponApplied.
